# Is it possible to add observer to tableView.contentOffset?

Tags: ios, uitableview, observer-pattern

I need to track tableView.contentOffset.y Is it possible to add observer to tableView.contentOffset?

I think this is impossible because contentOffset doesn't inherit NSObject class.

Is any other solution?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`UITableView` is a `UIScrollView` subclass so you can use the `UIScrollViewDelegate` method `scrollViewDidScroll:` to be notified when the view scrolled. Check the `contentOffset` of the `scrollView` in that method

`contentOffset` is a key path, so you can also observe its changes using KVO

```
[self.tableView addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"contentOffset" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld context:nil];
```

Comment: check out this swift example http://blog.scottlogic.com/2015/02/11/swift-kvo-alternatives.html

Answer (score 16):

Swift 5

```
tableContentObserver = table.observe(\UITableView.contentOffset, options: .new) { [weak self] table, change in
    self?.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.title = "\(change.newValue)"
}
```

Answer (score 7):

**Swift 3**

Add an observer for the `contentOffset` key path using Key-Value Observing (KVO):

```
tableView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(UIScrollView.contentOffset), options: [.old, .new], context: nil)
```

And handle notifications for changes:

```
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    if keyPath == #keyPath(UIScrollView.contentOffset) {
      // Your code
    }
  }
```

Comment: can you please add code for remove "contentOffset" observer?