# I'm dragging an UItableView. How do I find content offset

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a standard UITableViewContoller. You can see the initial position of UITableView.

[image: initial position]

You can see an offset when I'm dragging UITableView. Is it possible to find an offset when I'm dragging? I can find an offset when I end drag. How do I find an offset when I'm dragging?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to add observer to tableView.contentOffset?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12087848/is-it-possible-to-add-observer-to-tableview-contentoffset)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

delegate doesn't give much information. Observer is more good solution.

```
[self.tableView addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"contentOffset" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld context:nil];
```

[similar topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12087848/is-it-possible-to-add-observer-to-tableview-contentoffset)

Answer (score 0):

Because the UITableView is a subclass if UIScrollView, you can simply use the UIScrollViewDelegate protocol on your controller. If it is already the tableview delegate then simply add this protocol, and use the method `scrollViewDidScroll:`

Every time the user pulls the table down slightly, this method is called. There you can get the content offset as you already do :)